# UITextField keyboard: enable done button when no text is entered

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField in my app. When the user selects it, a keyboard is presented with a done button. The keyboard is dismissed by pressing the done button. But the done button is only enabled after the user has entered text. I want the user to have the option of dismissing the keyboard without entering text. Is it possible to enable the done button before text has been entered?

Comment: did you try `[uiButtonInstance setEnabled:YES];` ?

Comment: I figured out the solution (see below).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I discovered this is resolved by unchecking the Auto-enable Return Key property in the Attributes Inspector.